# UbuntuOne for Windows does not work - I got "Problem opening the ping_url" error

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, proxy, authentication, ping

When I try to login to existing account I got "Problem opening the ping_url" error.

Answer (score 3):

"OK. Solution is:

1. execute 'uninstall.exe'
2. kill ubuntuone processes (there were few processes - probably because of proxy) OR restart computer
3. remove 'C:\Program Files\ubuntuone' if exist
4. install again and works." - [thm](https://askubuntu.com/users/17587/thm), October 4th, 2011.