# Ubuntu One doesn't log in on Windows

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-xp, microsoft

I love using Ubuntu.

However I have a Windows XP desktop at work. I work alot between home and the office.
It would be great not to have to use Dropbox instead of U1 to sync my work.

U1 installs fine but whenever I try log in I get this error: [image]

I checked with the IT department and there are no proxies.
So I have no idea why it does this nor how to fix it.

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution mentioned in another post.
You might try this:
 [ubuntuone-for-windows-does-not-work-i-got-problem-opening-the-ping-url-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64282/ubuntuone-for-windows-does-not-work-i-got-problem-opening-the-ping-url-error)